# Using Odin to wipe out everything and restore factory settings

Tags: samsung, odin, android-device-manager

I have the Samsung Galaxy Tab 8 that has MDM installed.  I need to wipe out everything.  I was told that I need to flash the firmware.  I tried it with Odin v3.12.7 using a firmware Android version 6 from sammobile.com.  The original was v5.  It did flashed successfully to Android 6.  But the MDM is still being active.

In Odin there is an option for re-partition.  Will this wipe out everything including the Data partition (I assumed this is the partition that contain apps...)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using ODIN should wipe the device completely.  How do you know the MDM is still active?

Comment: @RMarkwald: When I tried to do a "Wipe Data/factory reset" in download mode, the "MDM does not allow factoryreset" pops up.  Also there is demo app auto-run by MDM....

Comment: What MDM is being used, is it from your company?  You may need to contact them to remove your device, and if they do, you reset it, don't connect it to your company's system again as the MDM will be pushed back down.  EDIT:  A re-partition will just fix the partitions if there is an issue.